# Overriding isEqual: method but it is not called when removing object from array

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, nsarray, foundation, nsobject

I'm using xCode 4.2, and going through the book "Programming in Objective C 2.0"

There is an exercise that involves implementing `isEqual:` method from the `NSObject` class.

The book says that the `isEqual:` method is triggered when the `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` method of the `NSArray` class is called. `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` ends up sending `isEqual:` message to all array members.

When I'm trying to implement this `isEqual:` method in my class `AddressCard`, and I use `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`, passing an object that is an instance of `AddressCard` class, however, my `isEqual:` method is not getting called. Although if I just use the `isEqual:` method on an instance of `AddressCard` explicitly, it does work.

Here is my `isEqual:` method from the AddressCard.m file

```
-(BOOL)isEqual: (id)object {
    NSLog(@"I got called");
    return NO;
}
```

When this code is fired in AddressBook.m

```
-(void) removeCard: (AddressCard *) theCard {
    [book removeObjectIdenticalTo: theCard];
}
```

the `isEqual:` method listed above is not called.

I feel like I'm missing something important, but from all I've read and I know, I think that `isEqual:` MUST be called, unless `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` does not involve it anymore.

I have all respective methods defined in .h files too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the book is in error.

`NSMutableArray` and other collections have some pairs of similar methods like `removeObject:` and `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` with important differences in their meanings.

The first tests whether the *values* of the objects in the collection are the same as the value of the passed-in object. In order to do this, an array calls `isEqual:` on each object in the array. This allows every class to define for itself what "equality" to another object means, as you are doing for your `AddressCard` class. Details about `removeObject:` can be found in [its documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBB):

> This method uses `indexOfObject:` to locate matches [...] Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the `isEqual:` message.

The `...IdenticalTo:` methods deal with the actual identity in memory of the objects. They check whether the address of the passed-in object is the same as that of any in the collection. An array can find the address of the object without calling any methods on that object; `isEqual:` is not used here. Again, this is stated in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDDBAG):

> This method uses the `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` method to locate matches [...] Thus, matches are determined using object addresses.

Generally speaking, you will want `removeObject:` much more often than `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`, since its meaning most closely matches the action you wish to perform: select the object whose *value* is the same as the supplied object's.

Answer (score 8):

As you guessed, `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` does not call `isEqual:` as it just uses the object addresses to check equality.

But `removeObject:` calls `isEqual:`, so you’ll most likely want that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there removeObjectIdenticalTo method listing somewhere? Because I was only able to jump to .h definition file.